# CNAME record for Azure app

Tags: asp.net, azure, dns, cname, azure-web-app-service

I want to create the CNAME-record for app service on Azure.
Host alias for CNAME-record should be with dot in the end.

Url of my app service: http://gorohaspnet20170124102612.azurewebsites.net/
But with dot in the end (http://gorohaspnet20170124102612.azurewebsites.net./) I get:

> HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.

P.S.: My Azure-account is free (Imagine) - perhaps this is the cause of the problem?

Comment: i don't think trial subscription is the issue here, trial subscription is not restricted in any way shape or form, as war as I know (except money, obviously)

Comment: Any chance you could provide the zone file as that might help troubleshoot the problem. I assume the dot at the end is just referring to the standard syntax of a zone file whereby any FQDN you point at has a dot at the end, right?

Comment: I think the "dot on the end" is a misunderstanding; you should not have that.